# How to configure Visual Studio Code extensions from command line

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-code

[Installing Visual Studio Code extensions from the command line is very simple](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions) is very simple. But lots of extensions require additional configuration to work.

Example: https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync#upload-your-settings-for-the-first-time
We have to open the command palette, type a specific command, the paste a Gist ID and hit Enter. Only then the extension can work.

Another example: https://github.com/wakatime/vscode-wakatime#installation
Here we have to restart/reload VSCode and then enter an API key before the installation is actually finished.

How can Visual Studio Code extensions be configured from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Got a reply on one of the extension's Github that this is not possible right now:

> Currently its Limitation from Code, editor doesnt allow extension to perform actions from CLI

https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync/issues/465#issuecomment-349903682

The [related issue for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35437) was closed :(

Comment: Glad to know that you get the answer now even if it has a limitation now. If possible, you could mark your reply as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue.

Comment: I don't consider the question answered yet.